# Transforming $dX=-X^2dt+2X\circ dW$ (a Stratonovich SDE) to Ito form

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

As the title says, I need to transform Stratonovich SDEs to Ito form. I get similar results for some, but very different results in others. How do I do this? Thanks a lot!

**A)** Stratonovich $dX=-X^2dt+2X\circ dW$ to Ito.

Attempt:

I believe that for a Stratonovich SDE
$$dX=\left(a-\frac{1}{2}b'b\right)dt+b\circ dW$$
its Ito form will be
$$dX=a dt+b dW$$

So I got that $b=2X$ and $a+\frac{1}{2}\times 2\times2X=-X^2$, so $a=-X^2-2X$ and the SDE in Ito form would be
$$dX=(-X^2-2X)dt+2XdW$$

However, the actual result is:
$$dX=(-X^2+X)dt+2XdW$$

I have the same problem with other conversions so I must be doing it wrong?

Comment: Another option could be that my professor made an error and worked it out wrong? He is notorious for making errors...

Comment: ahh...I see, $b'$ indicates the derivative wrt $x$...

Answer (score 4):

using your transformation formula (there is a $-$ instead of a $+$) (could you please give a reference?), then you just get:

$$
dX=\left(a-\frac{1}{2}b'b\right)dt+b\circ dW=dX=-X^2dt+2X\circ dW
$$
and therefore we get
$$
a+\frac{1}{2}b'b=-X^2 \text{ with } b=2X,b'=2
$$
which gives us
$$
a=-X^2+\frac{1}{2}b'b=-X^2+2X
$$
which again gives then the Ito representation
$$
dX=a dt+b dW=dX=(-X^2+2X)dt+2XdW
$$

Comment: The transformation formula wasn't in my lecture notes, but I googled it and found one here: https://www.pims.math.ca/files/monahan_2d.pdf (on the second page)

OK, thanks a lot! One more questoion if you don't mind... What is the formula for differentiating $b=2X$ to obtain $b'=-1$ (in general)?

Comment: @user133971 sorry, I just see my mistake, I will edit it right now. It seems your result is almost correct (sign error) and your prof did the mistake!

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @user133971 I checked the slides and indeed it is $a-1/2b'b$ instead of $a+1/2b'b$ which is still not the desired result

Comment: Thanks! I've checked the answers for the other SDEs in the exercises and they would be correct with the new formula... Sorry, I copied it wrong. However, my professor made a mistake in the SDE in part A.

Comment: @user133971 I am sure he did, since there is actually no way that we both calculated the wrong transformation, it is just plug in (thanks for the reference anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a stochastic process such as:
$$dX = udt + \sigma(t,\omega)\circ dW$$

to convert to its Ito form, the formula is:
$$dX = udt + \sigma(t,\omega)dW + \frac{1}{2}\sigma'(t, \omega)\sigma(t,\omega)dt$$

Your stochastic process is:
$$dX = -X^2dt+2X\circ dW$$

So $\sigma(t,\omega) = 2X$

Then, its Ito derivative would be:
$$dX = -X^2dt+2XdW + \frac{1}{2}(2)(2X)dt$$
$$dX = -X^2dt+2XdW + 2Xdt$$
$$dX = (-X^2 + 2X)dt+2XdW$$